# SyncStart with Codisys without PLCOPEN Part 4

Tags: plc, st, codesys

I need to Approximate A SyncStart/SyncStop Function in Codesys using PLCOPEN. I don't have access to Part 4 that contains the Synchronized motion stuff. Any ideas on how to start down the right path this in ST would be Awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you said there is not a syncstart/syncstop in this version of codesys.  If I were you I would

1. find which axis of motion has the longest distance to travel
2. find the total time it takes for that axis to travel that distance at its max velocity
3. find the time it takes for every axis you want to sync
4. get the ratio of the time for each axis over the time of the longest travel time
5. multiply that ratio to velocity, accel,decel, and jerk for the corresponding axis.

That will get you pretty darn close.